# how to assert for xml nodes

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have a question in regards to asserting an xml node and want to look at different scenarios an assertion can be performed.

Below I have an xml that contains a warning xml tag:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="xxx" xmlns:xsi="xxx" xmlns:xsd="xxx">
   <soap:Body>
      <xxxxmlns="xxx">
         <xxxUrl="xxx" TimeStamp="2017-03-16T12:36:01.8215426+00:00" IntCode="xxx">
            <Warnings>
               <Warning Code="xxx" Text="Price changed. Use the new RatePlanCode or BookingCode"/>
            </Warnings>
```

I want to perform a couple of different types of assertions to understand how to assert different features within an xml:

- Check if the xml contains a warning xml tag
- Check that if any warning tag contains a code that equals warnPriceChanged

These are just seperate checks so i can see how they work. Below is a sample code where I want to check if a warning tag is present but i am getting a null response:

```
def WarningCodes = xml.'soap:Body'.xxx[0].xxx[0].Warnings[0].Warning*.@Code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to take them in order:

**1) Check if the xml contains a warning xml tag**

If you're using XmlSlurper:

```
xml.'**'.any { it.name() == 'Warning' }
```

If you're using XmlParser:

```
xml.'**'.any { it.name().localPart == 'Warning' }
```

**2) Check that if any warning tag contains a code that equals warnPriceChanged**

If you're using XmlSlurper:

```
xml.'**'.findAll { it.name() == 'Warning' }.any { it.@Code == 'warnPriceChanged' }
```

If you're using XmlParser:

```
xml.'**'.findAll { it.name().localPart == 'Warning' }.any { it.@Code == 'warnPriceChanged' }
```

Comment: Glad to know the variants between `XmlSlurper` and `XmlParser`. But also `any`. Looks `collect` can also be used there for `any`? or any difference?